# What is a .Spritefont file, and how do I create it?

Tags: fonts, sprite, spritefont

I have looked for them for half an hour. I have a .TFF font, I have a .png spritesheet, I have everything I need to be able to write down any sort of string, but apparently I need  to load content in XNA as `userfont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>`

And this .SpriteFont filetype I can't find. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SpriteFont, you can import fonts directly.